# How can I connect scatter points using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I connect scatter points using matplotlib.pyplot
this is my code

```
x = data
y = pdf
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show
```

I am getting this plot

[image]

But I want it to be like this

[image: https://i.ibb.co/zHhzZ35/correct.png]

I tried to replace

`plt.scatter(x, y)`

by

`plt.plot(x, y)`

but I got something different

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get that correctly, I think you should sort the lists. You could do it like this:

```
# List indexes sorted
sorted_list = sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda a: x[a])

# Based on sorted indexes, sort lists
x = [x[i] for i in sorted_list]
y = [y[i] for i in sorted_list]

# Plot
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that with `numpy` you could use `np.argsort` instead of implementing it with list comprehension, and it's probably faster

Comment: Yeah that is true. :)